# Print actual binary representation of a file

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line, binary

I want to print the actual binary representation of a file. For example, give some text file `a.txt`:

```
This is some text
```

I can print its binary representation with:

```bash
$ python -c "import sys;print(''.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:08b}', open(sys.argv[1],'rb').read())))" a.txt
0101010001101000011010010111001100100000011010010111001100100000011100110110111101101101011001010010000001110100011001010111100001110100
```

I can achieve something similar using `xxd`, but the output is in hex not binary:

```bash
$ xxd -p a.txt
5468697320697320736f6d652074657874
```

`xxd` does have a flag to output binary `-b` but this is incompatible with the flag `-p` which lets you output just the raw data without offset/character information.

Wondering if there's a more elegant way to output the raw binary as shown above without needing to resort to python? Was hoping `xxd` or `hexdump` would be able to do this, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really stupid idea that does without python and uses `xxd` + `sed`:

```
$ printf 'This is some test' | xxd -p | sed 's/0/0000/g;s/1/0001/g;s/2/0010/g;s/3/0011/g;s/4/0100/g;s/5/0101/g;s/6/0110/g;s/7/0111/g;s/8/1000/g;s/9/1001/g;s/a/1010/g;s/b/1011/g;s/c/1100/g;s/d/1101/g;s/e/1110/g;s/f/1111/g;s/00/00/g;'
0101010001101000011010010111001100100000011010010111001100100000011100110110111101101101011001010010000001110100011001010111001101110100
```

Or a bit less stupid – have xxd output one octet per line (`-c1`), then paste all lines in a single line (`paste -sd ''`):

```
$ printf 'This is some test' | xxd -b -c1 | awk '{print $2}' | paste -sd ''
0101010001101000011010010111001100100000011010010111001100100000011100110110111101101101011001010010000001110100011001010111001101110100
```